# Python 2.7 string decode.

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the following Python 2.7 shell, I was expecting "s.decode('cp437')", and print(s) give me the same outputs, but they are not, what's reason here?

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'cp437'
>>> sys.stdin.encoding
'cp437'
>>>
>>> s = "Flügel"
>>> s
'Fl\x81gel'
>>> s.decode('cp437')
u'Fl\xfcgel'
>>>
>>> print(s)
Flügel
>>>
```

Comment: try `print(repr(s))`

Comment: Most likely it's the terminal's encoding that is influencing the encoding here. Try mangling with locales on your system - maybe run `LC_ALL=de_DE.cp437 python`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't caused by `str.decode`.  When you enter an object in the interactive shell, it prints the *representation* of that object, not the object itself.  For some types, like integers, these display the same thing:

```
>>> i = 42
>>> i
42
>>> print(repr(i))
42
>>> print(i)
42
```

For other types, like strings, they display two different things:

```
>>> s = 'Flügel'
>>> s
'Fl\x81gel'
>>> print(repr(s))
'Fl\x81gel'
>>> print(s)
Flügel
```

Similarly with a Unicode object:

```
>>> u = s.decode('cp437')
>>> u
u'Fl\xfcgel'
>>> print(repr(u))
u'Fl\xfcgel'
>>> print(u)
Flügel
```

It may be helpful (or confusing) to note that in the case of strings and Unicode objects, the object's representation is the Python code to instantiate it.  This may be clearer with a demonstration using `datetime.datetime`, which adopts the same paradigm:

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 20, 23, 59, 59)
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 20, 23, 59, 59)
>>> print(repr(d))
datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 20, 23, 59, 59)
>>> print(d)
2012-12-20 23:59:59
```

Answer (score 1):

`decode` will *return* the decoded value, not replace `s`.

If you want to alter your variable,

```
s = s.decode('cp437')
```

*(Interesting that the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) simply says it decodes the string, while the [encode documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) states it returns an encoded string)*

Comment: This is irrelevant - at least for the `s` and `s.decode('cp437')` commands - their output differ

Comment: The question is why `print(s)` and `decode` give different results.